# Include view in activity and pass a string to it through XML in the process

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I was making an activity for my app and I noticed I was essentially repeating code and just changing the String in a TextView. I had the idea of moving the code to a separate XML file and calling include on it to add it to my activity, and simply passing the String I need to it.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:weightSum="2"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/wear_calories"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/wear_calories"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

That's what my code currently looks like in the activity. The layout "wear_calories" is basically just a TextView, there's nothing to show.

So is there a way to pass "parameters" or anything like that through XML?

Comment: just give `android:id="@+id/youri=Id"` every time you are including the TextView

Comment: So I should change the contents of the layout in the activity's onCreate?

Comment: yes ! you can manage these  TextViews in  activity's onCreate.